# Flutter - I can't make a request to the EC2 integration environment endpoint

Tags: flutter, http, amazon-ec2, dio

I can't make a request to an AWS instance endpoint through Flutter. The line below is not even executed, as the code stops on the request.

```
Future getCode() async {
  Response response = await client.get(
    Uri.parse('http://ec2-54-202-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test/api/v1/example'),
  );

  print(response.statusCode);
}
```

I am able to perform this same request through Postman.

However, when I make a request via Flutter to the same endpoint, changing the first part of the domain (making the request for the Production environment and not for Homologation), it works:

**Integration URL (does not work in Flutter)**

> http://ec2-54-202-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com/test/api/v1/example

**Production URL (works in Flutter)**

> http://www.test.com/test/api/v1/example

I also emphasize that the integration environment is a copy of the production environment, which should allow access to both.

I believe that it is not necessary to make any changes to the server that receives these requests, as I can successfully make the request through Postman.

***How can I make this request through Flutter?***

Sample request URL for production environment
[image]

Sample request URL for homologation environment
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for the request to work by calling the endpont of the integration environment

For this it was necessary to use the badCertificateCallback and specify the certificate that I would like to allow access. I created a class specifying this:

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) {
        if (host.isNotEmpty &&
            host == 'ec2-54-202-27-94.sa-east-1.compute.amazonaws.com') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      };
  }
}
```

And in the project file that has the main function, add the following lines

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
```

This way:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();

    runApp(
      MyApp(),
    );
}
```

It is not appropriate to allow the use of insecure certificates in a production environment. Use only in Debug mode